# How to achieve replication of partial data for following use case

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, nosql, couchbase

I want to build a system with the following data replication requirements. 
In the image attached:

1. Node 1 has 2 entities Entity 1 and Entity 2.
2. Each entity has multiple rows of data say (Row1, Row2, Row3)
3. Node 2 and Node 3 are a full replica of Node1 and possibly in the same data center.
4. Node 4 sits in a different place altogether and has only Row 1 from Entity1 and Entity2.
5. Node 5 sits in another place and has only Row2 from Entity 1 and Entity2.

The idea is Node4 and Node5 will be in the geographic vicinity of the consumer system and the consumer can communicate with local copies in Node 4 and Node5 if the network is down.

On a normal business day - Its acceptable to limit all writes to Node1 and allow Node 4 or Node 5 to do the write only when Node 1 is down.

I am not sure which Database can support this without extensive management through code.

[Data Model Replication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To4gk.png)

So far I have found this:

1. Cassandra can do keyspace based replication but it might be tricky as I have 2000+ remote locations for partial data. I can think of having to say 200 keyspaces with 10 locations sharing same keyspace, thus creating less overhead, even though data copied to local nodes will not always be useful to them.
2. Mongodb has an open request for this feature (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1559)
3. Couchbase has XDCR based filtering, which looks like a potential solution.

Can you please suggest if my understanding is correct?

Comment: Comparing and asking for recommendation on different technologies are not good questions on stack overflow. This is because without know the problem in-depth it's hard to give a good answer. Please consider asking this question in a different way.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Paddy, I will try to frame questions better. I was not looking for technology comparison. I read up on all three to see which of the three can achieve this use case and documented what I found as three different options available. I was just looking for confirmation from community that these observations are correct. Looking back at question I think adding "Which database is correct" looks like asking for recommendation between three. Will try to avoid these in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Couchbase XDCR is a viable solution. You could 
1. set up Node 1, Node 4, and Node 5 as three separate data clusters
2. set up a uni-directional XDCR from Node 1 to Node 4 with a filtering expression that matches only Row 1
3. set up a uni-directional XDCR from Node 1 to Node 5 with a filtering expression that matches only Row 2.

For more information, please refer to https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/learn/clusters-and-availability/xdcr-overview.html.
XDCR filtering is at: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/learn/clusters-and-availability/xdcr-filtering.html

Comment: Thank you this helps and also matches my understanding so far on who can support this use case.